# Windows 7 won't acknowledge wireless

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

I've got a Windows 7 laptop, I've reinstalled drivers and everything. I get the wireless device to show but I do not see ANY wireless connections to connect too. I've ran a linux Live CD and could connect just fine. Ideas?

Comment: Did it ever work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the driver is correct, this is probably caused by a disabled radio switch  (might be a keyboard shortcut) or missing "hotkey" software that checks this switch and reports it to the wifi adapter.

Check if there is such hotkey software for your laptop and install it. Then try to enable the radio switch.

## In response to your comments:

If the radio switch seems to work and there are still no SSIDs listed (and there is at least one access point in reach that is broadcasting it's SSID) check for updated drivers. Realtek drivers are available on http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=21&Level=4&Conn=3.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that. Could this also be found under the settings/properties in the device manager? EDIT: Looked and couldn't find a setting. Also tried hotkeys on keyboard.

Comment: Yes, I have seen options to enable radio there at least on Intel adapters. But if you also have such an option it is probably independent of the mentioned radio switch and both must be enabled to get it working. I would also assume an option in the properties dialog would be enabled by default.

Comment: Was there any response on using the hotkeys/keyboard shortcuts? Usually there is some kind of on screen message to see the current status. Do other shortcuts work as expected (volume, brightness, external display, ...)

Comment: This is a Realtek adapter from what I can tell. There also was no radio options like I've seen with other devices. ;/ Yep, keys and everything work fine. ;/

Comment: So there is some feedback on screen or by a LED when you toggle the radio switch? Or just when changing other things like volume?

Comment: Sound, and the LED Radio switch for wifi toggles just fine. But no matter what I still don't get Windows picking up the wireless nets. I checked for 3rd party pluggins and got nothing.

Comment: @RachelNark Aside from ensuring the radio is switched is on, which it sounds like you've done all you can, so it probably IS on and it sounds like its broken.  Especially if this notebook was built within the last couple years.

Comment: Ok, then please see my updated answer. @techie007: Likely not broken, as it is working with the Linux live CD.

Comment: Me = duh -- I misread that as it wasn't working when a LiveCD was tried.

Comment: Download the correct drivers and still nothing. /lost

Comment: Even done complete format and reinstalled... nothing. Sollution: /install linux

Comment: Actually fixed it. Wiped it reinstalled every driver then messed around with the radio switch and it worked. Guess I was played the first time.